# Synapse Linked service reference in synapse notebook

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have created a REST linked service in Azure Synapse workspace. Now I need to refer this linked service in Synapse notebook. I tried the ArtifactsClient module to get the linked service reference, but no matter what I do, so or the other methods are not available.

```
from azure.synapse.artifacts import ArtifactsClient


credentials = DefaultCredentials()

synapse_client = ArtifactsClient(credentials=credentials, endpoint='https://<your-workspace-name>.dev.azuresynapse.net')


linked_service_name = 'REST_Dev_*'

linked_service = synapse_client.get_linked_service(linked_service_name=linked_service_name)
print(linked_service.properties)
```

When I run this code or other methods on Artifacts client object I always get the error like "this module does not have that method"

Can someone please help on this issue or suggest some ways to retrieve the existing linked service in notebook

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- The error occurs because there is no attribute called `get_linked_service()` for the `ArtifactsClient` object (you can use dir(ArtifactsClient) to check all available methods).
- To get the properties of the linked service, you need to use the `linked_service` attribute which is available with `ArtifactsClient` object. Then retrieve this object as a dictionary to access the `properties` property.
- The following is the code that worked for me:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.synapse.artifacts import ArtifactsClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential("<tenant_id>", "<client_id>", "<client_secret>")
synapse_client = ArtifactsClient(credential, endpoint='https://<your-workspace-name>.dev.azuresynapse.net')

linked_service_name = "RestService1"

linked_service = synapse_client.get_linked_service(linked_service_name=linked_service_name)

print(linked_service.as_dict()['properties'])
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- I have used the `service principle` to make connection but you can use what works for you (DefaultCredentials()).
- I ran the code in Visual Studio since it is a code issue and not workspace related and should work in synapse notebook as well.